# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in ListView item is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I'm trying to use a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in a `ListView` item. The `ListView` is inside a `Fragment` that's in an `Activity`. Since there are nested fragments I'm using the `getChildFragmentManager()` method to try to find the fragment from the XML layout. Here is the code.

**Java**

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_post_layout, null);
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_video);
if (youTubePlayerFragment == null) {
    Log.i("YouTube", "player is null");
} else {
    Log.i("YouTube", youTubePlayerFragment.toString());
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/post_base_layout" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <include layout="@layout/post_bottom_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when I try to create the fragment by doing `findFragmentById()` to get it from the XML, it returns null, and that's what is posted to the stack trace.

I'm trying to follow the YouTube API samples and make the changes needed for nested fragments but I can't find out what's causing the issue.

Comment: Can you share the output of this command `adb shell dumpsys activity <activity-name>`? It contains the active and added fragments list.

Comment: do you use support library fragments?

Comment: Yes. I have support library fragments.

Comment: Using fragments inside a listview makes no sense, and as far as I know cannot actually work. You should try the [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) alternative.

Comment: You can try changing "getChildFragmentManager" to "getSupportChildFragmentManager" - sometimes It helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with the whole approach you have taken.

First, inflating child fragments directly from an XML is [not supported](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). When nesting fragments, you must add them dinamically using `getChildFragmentManager` in the parent fragment.

Second, even if it worked (and it might in some cases), you have inflated the view but not added it to the actual fragment's layout. That's what the [second and third parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) in the `inflate` method are there for. The `FragmentManager` will look for fragment in its current layout, or event in the backstack, but can't find fragments inflated in a random XML and never put to use.

Finally, and most important, you should never add fragments as items in an `ListView`. Fragments expect to have a lifecycle tied to the Activity they are in, while a `ListView`, or any `AdapterView` in general, will create, destroy and recycle its children as needed.

Possible solutions:

- How many videos do you need on your list? If there are not many of them, a ScrollView+LinearLayout might actually be the easiest solution.
- If you really need View recycling, maybe you can do without live video in every row? Consider using a [YouTubeThumbnailView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeThumbnailView?hl=es) in your rows, then redirecting your user to another activity / loading a the video in a single `YoutubeFragment` located outside of the list on your layout.
- If you definitely want videos playing directly on every row in the list, you will need to use [YoutubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) instead of fragments on your row layout. In this case, read the documentation carefully, because you will need to handle the video initialization and view recycling yourself.

Comment: I have tried to use YouTubePlayerView inside listview but there is problem occured of initialization for each and every row. Then i have also tried listview with the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment but same way when queue video it changes the position to loaded video. It is not load in every row. can you share any example for each row live video play.

Answer (score 1):

your app will crash When you try to inflate view with same `Fragment` every `ListView` item (As duplication in fragment id like this [quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468936/duplicated-id-in-fragment-youtubeplayersupportfragment))

There Two solution (one of them from [@ivagarz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107940/ivagarz) answer) :

1- You can display only one youtube video Using `YouTubePlayerView` above your `ListView` into your `Activity` layout But your `Activity` Must extends `YouTubeBaseActivity` Like [YouTube Android Player API Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) (I Think this Solution will not help you to solve your problem)

2- you can use `YouTubeThumbnailView` to Display youtube Thumbnail Image of Video for Every Item into `ListView` with youtube player button over youtube Thumbnail Image Used to Display Video.

**Like** The next Picture :

[image]

**When** User click on youtube player button, You Have two ways:

**First** option using `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` : you can replacing `YouTubeThumbnailView` with `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` 
If you take This Option you must :

A- add `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` programmatically on the Fly (to avoid duplication in `Fragment` Id).

B- Display Only one Video into your `ListView` As [answer of this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117164/android-multiple-youtube-videos-in-activity/17156234#17156234).

**Ex**:

`list_item.xml` layout for `ListView` item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/parent_relativeLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/color_background_transparent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/btnYoutube_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube_player"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in `getView` mehtod of `ListView` adapter:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item.xml, parent, false);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
    final YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);

    // get parent relative layout
    RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_relativeLayout);
    // then create dynamic FrameLayout
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams dynamicFrameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    final FrameLayout dynamicFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(ctx);
        dynamicFrameLayout.setId(Different_ID);
        dynamicFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(dynamicFrameLayoutParams);
    // then add dynamic FrameLayout as children in parent relative layout
    parentRelativeLayout.addView(dynamicFrameLayout);

    ImageView youtubePlayerButton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
    youtubePlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View parentView = (View) v.getParent().getParent();
            YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            YouTubeFragment youTubeFragment = new YouTubeFragment();
                youTubeFragment.youTubeFragmentInitialize(VideoID, youTubeFragment, parentView);

            getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(dynamicFrameLayout.getId(), youTubeFragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

    final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            loadingImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID);
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
}
```

I was created my own `Fragment` extends from `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` :

```
public class YouTubeFragment  extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    public void youTubeFragmentInitialize(final String videoId, final YouTubeFragment fragment, final View parent) {

        fragment.initialize(apiKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

           youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                Log.e("app", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Second** option using `YouTubeStandalonePlayer` or creating your Own `Activity` extends `YouTubeBaseActivity` : Just when User click on youtube player button, you can create an Intent to open new activity to display Video

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);
 startActivity(intent);
```