# YouTubePlayerFragment in ListView with AppCompatActivity Error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-view, android-youtube-api

I am developing one android application. In this application I want youtube video play with youtube player in `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with `AppCompatActivity`. I have used `YouTubeBaseActivity` it is working well with this, but I need `AppCompatActivity`. So I used `YouTubePlayerFragment`or `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` for solving my problem.

When I am using `YouTubePlayerFragment` with `AppCompatActivity` then its working well. But I want to use this in `ListView`, but I'm getting following error.

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f0b0063, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0b0062 with another fragment for com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3611)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6182)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                 at com.example.youtubecardview.frag_youtube.custom_youtube_list_adapter.getView(custom_youtube_list_adapter.java:63)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6549)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6549)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6549)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6549)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6549)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:699)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21783)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1497)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1750)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1385)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6722)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:886)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:633)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:872)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
```

**1. Main2Acitivy.java**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mContext = this;
        mActivity = this;

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        List<String> mVideoIDList = new ArrayList<>();
        mVideoIDList.add("KSGYVl4ZgRs");
       // mVideoIDList.add("nCgQDjiotG0");
       // mVideoIDList.add("P3mAtvs5Elc");


        mList.setAdapter(new custom_youtube_list_adapter(mContext,mVideoIDList,mActivity));


        /**
         * @usages
         * check YouTubePlayerFragment is working with main activity or not
         *
         * @status  :  #Working
         */

        /*
         YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
         youtubeFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("KSGYVl4ZgRs");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                });*/

    }
}
```

**2. activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.youtubecardview.frag_youtube.Main2Activity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3. custom_youtube_list_adapter.java**

```
public class custom_youtube_list_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> aList;
    private Context aContext;
    private Activity aActivity;
    public custom_youtube_list_adapter(Context mContext, List<String> mList, Activity mActivity){

        aList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.aContext = mContext;
        this.aList = mList;
        this.aActivity =mActivity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return aList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return aList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     mHolder  holder;


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) aContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v;

        if (convertView == null) {
            v =inflater.from(aContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_frag_youtube_list, null);
            //v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_frag_youtube_list, null);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) aActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment1);

        youtubeFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(aList.get(position));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                });

        return v;
    }

    class mHolder {

    }
}
```

**4. custom_frag_youtube_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, please suggest me where am I wrong? How to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I am using @azizbekian solution.This is solve my problem inflate exception but I have same video with multiple layout.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;
        YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) aContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            View temp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_frag_youtube_list, parent, false);
            final int id = View.generateViewId();
            temp.setId(id);
            youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
            aActivity.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(id, youtubeFragment)
                    .commit();
            view = temp;
            view.setTag(youtubeFragment);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            youtubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)view.getTag();
        }

        youtubeFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                      Log.e("Youtube Position: ",""+position);
                      Log.e("Youtube list value: ",""+aList.get(position));
                      youTubePlayer.cueVideo(aList.get(position));
                        }
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                });


            return view;
      }
```

**Log Value:**

> Youtube Position:: 0
>
> Youtube list value:: KSGYVl4ZgRs
>
> Youtube Position:: 1
>
> Youtube list value:: nCgQDjiotG0

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I have resolve all problem instead of one problem. if i play video after playing one video that time adapter not refresh. so that i am unable to handle video playing at one time.

**UPDATE 3:**

After lot of searching and @azizbekian soluion,  I have resolved my problem.  by using following solution.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final mHolder holder;
        final View fview;
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) aContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new mHolder();
            fview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_youtube_frag_listview_list, parent, false);
            holder.mLoaderFrame = (ImageView) fview.findViewById(R.id.imgLayer1);
            fview.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            fview = convertView;
            holder = (mHolder) fview.getTag();
        }

        String VideoID = aList.get(position);

        /**
        * @usages
        * https://img.youtube.com/vi/VideoID/0.jpg
        * 
        * where 
          VideoID is ur youtube video id
          YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_URL_VIDEO1  = https://img.youtube.com/vi/
          YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_URL_VIDEO2  = /0.jpg
        */

        String mURL = YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_URL_VIDEO1 + VideoID + YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_URL_VIDEO2;

        Glide.with(aContext).load(mURL).into(holder.mLoaderFrame);
        holder.mLoaderFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(mCounterLeaveremove != 0){
            int mId = position+1;

            if(mCounterLeaveremove != mId){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = aActivity.getFragmentManager();
                Fragment oldFragment = null;
                try {
                    oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(mId);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(oldFragment != null) {
                    // Delete fragmet from ui, do not forget commit() otherwise no action
                    // is going to be observed
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
                }
            }

        }

        holder.mLoaderFrame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mCounterLeaveremove = position+1;

                notifyDataSetChanged();

                YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment;

                final int id = position+1;
                fview.setId(id);
                youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();

                aActivity.getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(id, youtubeFragment)
                        .commit();

                youtubeFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                        new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                                Log.e("Youtube Position: ", "" + position);
                                Log.e("Youtube list value: ", "" + aList.get(position));

                                holder.mLoaderFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                String VideoID = aList.get(position);

                                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VideoID);
                                youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {

                                    }
                                });

                                youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(0);

                                /**
                                 * @usages
                                 * 1. Listener use for manage video thumbnail and youtube player
                                 */
                                new custom_youtube_list_adapter.MyPlayerStateChangeListener(holder.mLoaderFrame);
                                new custom_youtube_list_adapter.MyPlaybackEventListener(holder.mLoaderFrame);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                            }
                        });

            }
        });

        return fview;
    }
```

For getting youtube video thumnail, you can go throw.

[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f0b0063, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0b0062 with another fragment for com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment

The problem is, that you are trying to inflate multiple fragments with same id, that's not possible. So, instead of adding `YouTubePlayerFragment` into the `xml` file, create it in the java code. Thus, `custom_frag_youtube_list.xml` will change to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

    View view;
    YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment;

    if (convertView == null) {
        View temp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_frag_youtube_list, parent, false);
        final int id = View.generateViewId();
        temp.setId(id);
        youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
        activity.getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(id, youtubeFragment)
                .commit();
        view = temp;
        view.setTag(youtubeFragment);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        youtubeFragment = view.getTag();
    }


    // interact with youtubeFragment
    ...

    return view;
}
```

---

### Update

Judging by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156234/1083957), it seems like Google won't allow multiple youtube videos to be played simultaneously.

Comment: thanks for solution but i have little more problem with this. I have same video play in both view. can u suggest me for this how to solve?

Comment: In the `interact with youtubeFragment` part perform `youtubeFragment.initialize(...)` with appropriate video id depending on the adapter's current position. It seems like you are requesting the same video for both items.

Comment: i have used but i am getting same video (Last video ID) with both view.

Comment: @rockstar, can you put a log in `onInitializationSuccess()` and print `aList.get(position)`, verifying log is printed N times with distinct video id-s?

Comment: @rockstar, please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156234/1083957).

Comment: ok but it can be manage with onclick but in your case every view having same action. this can not perform different action from different view.

Comment: please check my update i have updated my code on dropbox .

Comment: i have resolve all problem instead of one problem. if i play video after playing one video that time adapter not refresh. so that i am unable to handle video playing at one time. can you solve my problem? i have uploaded my code at Dropbox. you can download my code. please check my update.

Comment: thank u sir for giving me valuable time and solution.