# Display a list of Youtube Videos in Android inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

i want display a list oy youtube videos inside a listView.
i am using a fragment not an activity.
here is the fragment :

```
public class VideosFragment extends Fragment{
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //assign video
    mVideosListView = getView().findViewById(R.id.videoLV);

    fetchVideos();

    /***populate video list to adapter**/
    mVideoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getContext(), mVideosList, this);
    mVideosListView.setAdapter(mVideoAdapter);
}
}
```

**fragment_videos layout** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".VideosFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/videoLV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in my adapter i am trying to insert multiple YouTubePlayerSupportFragment dynamically .

**VideoAdapter** :

```
public class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Video> {

private Context mContext;
private Fragment frgmt;
private List<Video> mVideos;

public VideoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Video> objects, Fragment frg) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_row_video, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mVideos = objects;
    frgmt = frg;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment videoFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_row_video, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.videoView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = frgmt.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.videoView, videoFragment).commit();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }try {
        Video video = mVideos.get(position);
        final String url = video.getVideoUrl(); // your URL here

        videoFragment.initialize("AIza.....13Ao", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    if (!b) {
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(url);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
                    if (result.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                        result.getErrorDialog(frgmt.getActivity(), 1).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(frgmt.getActivity(), "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationFailure(): " + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Youtube Video error", e.getMessage());
    }
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    FrameLayout videoView;
}
}
```

and this is **single_row_video** layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

the problem is i am getting a single video displayed from the list , the other fragments looks empty , i dont know if it's a clean way to achieve my goal.
is there any better idea or a change to do it ? thank you.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/tree/master/core-sample-app/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/aytplayersample/examples/recyclerViewExample

This is using a different YouTube player, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment videoFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
```

You create instance of this fragment each time `getView` called, but add it to a viewholder only onces (that's why u have only one video). The concept of ViewHolder is - create view ones and re-use it. But you don't reuse it.

Your code should look something like this:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment videoFragment;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_row_video, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.videoView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment()
        FragmentTransaction transaction = frgmt.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.videoView, videoFragment).commit();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        videoFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) frgmt.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.videoView)
    } 
    videoFragment.initialize(...)
```

### Update

Judging by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156234/1083957), it seems like YouTube Android Player SDK does not allow multiple youtube videos to be played simultaneously.

Comment: i tried your solution but i still get the same case , only one video is shown and second empty cardView , i am really stucking at this issue , thx for your help.