# Duplicated ID in Fragment YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube, fragment

I am trying use API Youtube to execute play video, but I get a error in XML Duplicated ID  0x7f080039. Any idea how to solve this problem?

My Fragment exends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment :

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_video, container, false);

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
                (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        return view;
    }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feed_video_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#424346"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Error:

```
Process: br.com.dotazone, PID: 18375
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at br.com.dotazone.view.fragment.ChannelYoutubeFragment.onCreateView(ChannelYoutubeFragment.java:79)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:704)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6388)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f080039, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentyer.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
```

Comment: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically. Read *Nested Fragments* @ http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error occurs on Nested Fragments  which has been defined in layout , try remove your Fragment from Xml Layout and replace it with a FrameLayout as a PlaceHolder then instantiate your Fragment dynamically in code.

Comment: @DouglasMesquita did you implemented successfully? if yes can you share solution because when i tried to play video in each and every row then it not maintain position for queue.

Comment: @AnantShah yes. My code is on [github] [1]  [1]: https://github.com/douglasalipio/dotazone/blob/master/dota-zone/dotazone/src/main/java/br/com/dotazone/view/fragment/YouTubePlayerSupportCustomFragment.java

Comment: @DouglasMesquita your github link shows 404 error please update link and thank you for sharing link.

Comment: @AnantShah yes. My code on Github [Inline Link](https://github.com/douglasalipio/dotazone/blob/master/dota-zone/dotazone/src/main/java/br/com/dotazone/view/fragment/YouTubePlayerSupportCustomFragment.java)